# Hierarchical package structure in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, package, hierarchical

I am working with eclipse on an android project. I want to have packages inside of packages inside of packages and so on...

The problem is I can only have 1 type of subpackage. (I want more depth)
At the moment my project looks like this:

```
- com.company.main
  - subpackone
    + class1
    + class2
    + class3
  - subpacktwo
    + class4
  - subpackthree
    + class5
```

But what I want is something like this:

```
- com.company.main
  - subpackone
    + class1
    + class2
    + class3
    - subpacktwo
      + class4
      - subpackthree
        + class5
```

When I try to create more packages inside of subpackages it just changes the name of the already existing subpackage. I already set the Package Presentation to Hierarchical in eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flafoux gave me the right answer in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772388/hierarchical-package-structure-in-eclipse#comment49597378_30772388):

> You should have class in the package parent to be displayed, otherwise it will rename to the child you create
>
> – flafoux Jun 11 '15 at 6:37

My problem was that I tried to create new packages inside of packages that have no classes (to test it). But if I create a class inside the package first I then can create new subpackages.